# What does this function do in Haskell? I'm confused with the type

Tags: haskell

```
q3 a (b:[]) = a b
q3 a (b1:b2:bs) = q3 a (b2:bs)
```

It seems like `a` doesn't have any influence to the function. My understanding is that this function takes two parameters, where the second one is a list, and returns the first parameter and the tail of the second list.
However, I'm confused by the type:

```
q3 :: (t1 -> t) -> [t1] -> t
```

How is `a` relevant to `t1 -> t`?
Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier to understand had it been defined `q3 f [x] = f x; q3 f (_:xs) = q3 f xs`, which is exactly the same.

Comment: Remember that in haskell, function application is just a space!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line of the function has `a b` after the equal sign. Thus `a` has to be a function since that is a function application. Since `b` is the type of the elements of the list then `a` is a function from the type of elements in the list to the return type of the function.

The function just applies `a` to the last element of the list. Thus, it is similar to `a . last`.

Comment: Oh right! Functions in Haskell only have one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite this function.

```
q3 :: (t1 -> t) -> [t1] -> t
q3 a (b:[]) = a b
q3 a (b1:b2:bs) = q3 a (b2:bs)
```

to 'usual' style

```
q3 :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> b
q3 f (a:[]) = f a
q3 f (a1:a2:as) = q3 f (a2:as)
```

Now it is easy to see, that `q3 f as = f (last as)`. Function `q3` apply function `f` to the last element of the list `as`